Python SQL executemany DELETE statement runs successfully without error for no matching records found
I have a file which has 100 of records to get deleted from a table. I'm using cx_oracle connect connection with executemany statement from Python to Oracle SQL and trying to delete the entire 100 records 1 by 1 with matching primary key. The run completes successful, eventhough some of the records are not present in the table. I want the statement to error out, if any 1 of the records is not present in the table. How to achieve this?
I tried with executemany -
STNSchemaConnection = cx_oracle.connect(self._oracleUserNameSTN, self._oraclePasswordSTN, cx_oracle.makedsn(self._oracleServer, self._oraclePort, self._oracleSID))               
STNSchemaCursor = STNSchemaConnection.cursor()
STNSchemaCursor.prepare(deleteSqlString)
STNSchemaCursor.executemany(None,dataToDump)
STNSchemaConnection.commit()

the deleteSqlString has the delete query and the dataToDump has the 100 records in array.
deleteSqlString =
DELETE FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME
WHERE SOURCE_SYS   = :array_val_1
AND   CONTRACT_NUM = :array_val_2


Run a single statement deleting everything … WHERE IN …, then check the number of affected rows afterwards? I’m not sure about Oracle specifics, but that’s what I’d do in any regular SQL.

Don't forget to schedule your upgrade to the latest version of cx_Oracle, which was released under the new name python-oracledb a couple of years ago, see the release announcement.  There are many reasons to update.

If using WHERE IN, review the documentation on binding: https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-multiple-values-to-a-sql-where-in-clause

You can wrap your statement in a PL/SQL block to check whether zero rows were deleted and raise an exception within Oracle:
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME
  WHERE SOURCE_SYS   = :array_val_1
  AND   CONTRACT_NUM = :array_val_2;

  IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
    RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND;
  END IF;
END;

fiddle

throw error on your own. Something like this can help.
if STNSchemaCursor.rowcount < len(dataToDump):
    raise RuntimeError(
        f"Error: Expected to affect {len(dataToDump)} rows, but only {STNSchemaCursor.rowcount} rows were affected."
    )
else:
    print(f"Success: All {STNSchemaCursor.rowcount} rows affected as expected.")


